# Python / Pandas abbreviating my numbers.

Tags: python, csv, pandas, glob

Probably a very easy fix, but my english isn't good enough to search for the right answer.

Python/Pandas is changing the numbers that I'm writing from: 6570631401430749 to something like: 6.17063140131e+15

I'm merging hundreds of csv files, and this one column comes out all wrong. The name of the column is "serialnumber" and its the 3rd column.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
df_list = []

for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
    frame = pd.read_csv(filename)
    print(os.path.basename(filename))
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(filename)
    df_list.append(frame)
full_df = pd.concat(df_list)
full_df.to_csv('output.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: How are you viewing the resulting CSV? Are you sure the scientific notation is really being written into the file, and not an automatic conversion performed by whatever you are using to look at the file? (For example, if you open a CSV in Excel, it will often show you something different than what is stored in the file.)

Comment: Yes. I opened it in Notepad++, so the conversion really happened.

Comment: Good thinking though. My coworkers keep walking into that. Excel really does a number on numbers and formatting in general sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dtype = object` when you read csv if you want to preserve the data in its original form. You can change your code to

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
df_list = []

for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
    frame = pd.read_csv(filename,dtype=object)
    print(os.path.basename(filename))
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(filename)
    df_list.append(frame)
full_df = pd.concat(df_list)
full_df.to_csv('output.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. The boss wanted the CSV files read in manually, and it would have taken me a few hours at least. So happy this worked.

Comment: Glad it helped.